# list内各要素で計算

Tags: python3

```
list_1 = [100, 150, 200, 250]
```

上記のリストがあります。
説明が少し難しいのですが、
異なる各要素毎で計算するにはどうすればよろしいでしょうか？

求める回答

```
# 下記のように各要素で計算するロジックを組みたいです。
100 + 150
100 + 200
100 + 250
150 + 200
150 + 250
200 + 250

# 結果
[250, 300, 350, 350, 400, 450]
```

分かる方がいましたらご教示願います。
よろしくお願い致します。

Comment: ほとんど同じ(内容の)質問と, その回答が付いてる訳なので, 同じようにできるのでは？
[隣り合う二つの要素計算](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/83736/)

Comment: コメントありがとうございます。同じような共通する部分があるか再度見直します。

Answer (score 1):

```py
from itertools import combinations

list_1 = [100, 150, 200, 250]
result = list(map(sum, combinations(list_1, 2)))
print(result)

#
[250, 300, 350, 350, 400, 450]
```

Comment: コメントありがとうございます。itertoolsを使用すると出来るんですね。
勉強になります。
いつもコメントして下さりありがとうございます。

Comment: itertools には便利関数(convinient functon)が多数用意されているので、時間のある時にでも眺めておくと良いかと思います。 [itertools](https://docs.python.org/ja/3/library/itertools.html)

Comment: 補足コメントありがとうございます。そう致します。
ありがとうございます。